# foreach shuffle or array_rand() from a function from an include file

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, shuffle

I have a variable that is getting an array from an include file and i want to use a foreach from that array on a different file and have it display a random id from my array.

Here the array that i have from an include file. (From /products.php)

```
function get_all() {
$products = array();
$products[101] = array(
    "name" => "Red",
    "img" => "img-101.jpg",
    );
$products[102] = array(
    "name" => "Blue",
    "img" => "img-102.jpg",
    );
$products[103] = array(
    "name" => "Green",
    "img" => "img-103.jpg",
    );
foreach ($products as $product_id => $product) {
    $products[$product_id]["sku"] = $product_id;
}
return $products;
}
```

(From display.php)
Now I iwant to call the function from products.php into a variable and have it go through the foreach loop. Here is my code below..

```
 require_once include("products.php");

$random = function get_all();
$shuffle = shuffle($random);

foreach($shuffle as $product) { 
    echo $product["name"];
    echo $product["img"];
}
```

This is the code that i tried but it keeps on spitting out errors saying the variable is undefined.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here? and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://us2.php.net/shuffle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u_mulder is showing you an implementation error

change this

```
$shuffle = shuffle($random);
```

to the following

```
shuffle($random);
```

watch out for this error, go to the [manual/shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and check the function signature

```
bool shuffle ( array &$array )
```

This function returns a boolean, and will affect your array due to it passing as a reference. The rest seems like it should work

Comment: Thanks..putting shuffle($random) worked.. I also had to change the foreach back to $random as $products..

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
$random = get_all();
shuffle($random);

foreach($random as $product) {
    echo $product["name"];
    echo $product["img"];
}
```

Instead of

```
 $random = function get_all(); 
 $shuffle = shuffle($random);
```

Comment: Don't forget that `shuffle` returns **bool**

Comment: @u_mulder Why don't you post an answer?